# MongoDB and Admin UIs

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to search about `MongoDB` for `Java`, its own site is good.
But i want to learn much and its `Admin UIs`,is any book you can recommend to me? or any other good blog? Thanks.

Comment: MongoDB 50 tips & tricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually free mongoDB online course ends yesterday. But you could register for next mongoDB course or start read mongo tutorials.

> courses: https://education.10gen.com/courses

or

> tutorial:
>    http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/

It was awesome course and i am really recommend you to enroll this course.

Comment: damn it, it start next year, but i can wait ,it will interesting ,I never would have guessed it would be such a course,thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the admi UI's once you start using it
i use mongoVUE for windows http://www.mongovue.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/greenmangoquery
http://greenmangoquery.blogspot.sg/
its swing based client for mongodb . pretty simple and light weight.